# Deleting files from a list on the server without actually syncing them?

Tags: ssh, rsync

I have a situation, where I want to `rsync` a few scripts to the server:

```
rsync -arh --stats --files-from="${LIST}" "${SRC}/" "${HOST}":"${DST}/"
```

In the next step I would `ssh` into the server and call some of the scripts.

When the job is done, I want to remove the uploaded list of files.

In a nutshell I have some scripts which are engaged to a directory structure, therefore things like `ssh "${HOST}" rm -rf "${DST}/"` cannot be considered, as `${DST}` contains other files.

Is there a way to achieve *undo* of `rsync` without using very exotic tool set?

Answer (score 1):

```
< "$LIST" ssh $HOST xargs -i% rm "$DST/%"
```

Using a single ssh session.

Assumes your list is of files and does not contain directories, unpicking the latter could be onerous.

*EDIT: To explain this previous remark, given that the question does not include a sample of the input file, one has to make assumptions about it.*

My answer should be able to handle it if the input file looks similar to this:

```
script1.sh
script2.sh
script3.sh
```

If your input file was like this:

```
script1.sh
script2.sh
somedir/
```

(IE having a whole **directory** to copy) then it would prove to be more difficult to know what to delete with regard to `somedir/` (we'd have to enumerate `somedir/` locally and use that information to do the clean up).

Answer (score 0):

You already have the list of files, so the easiest way, since you say there are only a few scripts, would be to iterate the same file (say `file.list`) and erase them.

Something along these lines:

```
for r in "$(cat ${LIST})"
do
  ssh "${HOST}" rm "${DST}/$r"
done
```

Comment: Yep, something among the lines would work. But that would mean one ssh connections per file, which is probably ok, but not ideal. 
I could refactor my scripts to accept the path, in where they operate, in the argument, but it's ugly...

Comment: You said there were just a few. If I were you, I'd put the above iteration in an additional clean-up script. Then, you run that script at then end and you just remove the clean-up script (it could also remove itself if you want to skip that last connection).